# Is it possible to send messages to your ISAPI Extention from WCF?

Tags: wcf, web-services, iis, isapi, isapi-extension

thanks for taking the time to read this. I'm new to IIS/WCF and had a question regarding its capabilities.

We want to put an ISAPI extension in our IIS to route requests to different servers/services depending on some static data. When IIS is started and the ISAPI extension is run, it accesses the WCF to retrieve information on which servers are active to route various requests to. My question is, if this data is changed, and WCF is restarted... is there a way I can send updated data from my WCF to IIS to update the data in my ISAPI extension?

Any help or information on this would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: From above description what i understand it the next time your IIS uses the ISAPI extension it will be goint to query WCF for the routing server details. So in which case you want the WCF to provide details to ISAPI extension.